# Header for CStdioFile , if I am already including windows.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cstdio

Which header shall i use for CStdioFile?

The relevant doc is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b61hcx0(v=vs.120).aspx)

when I try including afx.h , i get following error( window.h is included before afx.h because of some other function):

Error   1   error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h

I wan to remain in native C++ world.

I am using visual studio 2013

If there is a basic setting in project properties that is relevant here, please let me know.

Comment: because you are not using precompiled headers you cannot use afx.h? Could you elaborate that? Why not include afx.h where you need it?

Comment: Actually  I am using windows.h  and it seems that conflict with using afx.h . In the light of your comment I am editing original question with error when I try to include both.

Comment: what if you flip the include order?

Comment: I flipped. Now, I am getting link errors e.g. Error 4 error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dllmain.obj)